# Wanted: practical guide on data modeling the agile way

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm curious how agile methodologies do data modeling (conceptual and logical schemas). I've read a couple of articles on agile but I haven't really encountered **a practical guide** on agile data modeling for small development teams. Any articles or books that you can recommend?

Comment: this kind of philosophy is sort of built in to Enterprise Elements Repository - where any change to the models immediately reflect in the UI.  Not much to read up on however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an essay/website which might help.

[Agile Data Modeling 101](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html)

Comment: Conceptual data modeling hardly exists other than see Halpin links from cited article.

Answer (score 1):

For conceptual patterns - look up books by David Hay and Len Silverston